# WebSphere: Unable to change both stderrfilname and stdoutfilename at same time

Tags: websphere, stdout, native, jython, wsadmin

In WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 I'm having problems setting the native_stdout and native_stderr log paths from wsadmin jython script.
Everytime I set one path, the other is blanked out. i.e. set to null.
I presume I need to form a line of code that sets both paths simultaneously but have been unable to create the correct syntax, if this is at all possible.
The code to produce one path change looks like:

```
srv = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/Server:server1/')
processDef = AdminConfig.list('JavaProcessDef', srv)
AdminConfig.modify(processDef, [['ioRedirect', [['stderrFilename', '${LOG_ROOT}/server1/new_stderr.log']]]])
AdminConfig.save()
```

This works fine but when I then use the same script to set the stdoutFilename, it blanks the stderrFilename previously set.

It seems to make no difference at which point I commit the changes using save.

Any help with this issue would be greatly received!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, even though the manual elsewhere warns that AdminConfig.modify() might append to lists when you don't expect it to.  I observed the same thing.

Here's the pattern you want to be safe, clear it out and set both properties at the same time:

```
AdminConfig.modify(processDef, [['ioRedirect', []]])
AdminConfig.modify(processDef, [['ioRedirect', [['stderrFilename', '${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/my_stderr.log'], ['stdoutFilename', '${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/my_stdout.log']]]])
```

After this, you can do this for a simple verification:

```
print AdminConfig.showall(processDef)
```

But watch the output closely as it is not pretty-printed

Comment: Superb! I'm sure I must have tried that exact syntax in my many attempts but just missed the results.  Many thanks for your prompt response and help.